# jQuery on the parent div but not the child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have this

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

How can I have jQuery do something when .parent is clicked on, as long as .child2 is not clicked? I tried using event.stopPropagation() but it didn't work. 
This is what I have:

```
$('body').on({
    click: function(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
},'.child2');

$('body').on({
    click: function()
    {
        //blah blah
    }
},'.parent');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stopPropagation` method of the event object:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function(){
  // ...
}).find('.child2').on('click', function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8bqM/

Comment: If I want to keep everything live (so the div might be added once the page is loaded), how do I do that?

Comment: Just change "on" to "live"

Comment: Live is no longer supported in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

it actually works with stop propagation. see the code below, it worked for me.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".parent").click(function(){
    alert("this is test");
});
$(".parent div").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

});

});

http://jsfiddle.net/rameshwor/p4MFb/1/

Comment: Weird, it doesn't work for me! I've deleted all my code, and all I have is basically just alerting stuff, but it doesn't work!!

Comment: That's the same answer like the one from @undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').on('click', function() {
        alert('parent');
    }); 

    $('.child2').on('click', function() {
        $('.parent').off('click');
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3n3p/

Comment: Your code permanently turns clicking off! So if I click on .child2, then I can no longer click on .parent